# Checking Array for null element

Tags: java, arrays, null, nullpointerexception

So I've created my own class with 5 private fields: Each is an array with a pre-set length. It's my way of creating a table, where each array is a column, and they have pre-set lengths because not every cell will contain an element (So, not using anything dynamic).

Anyway, my question is: Can I check to see if a specific cell of a specific array contains "null"? Using .equals(null) gives a nullpointerexception :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.equals(...)` you call a method of the object. If it is null, it has no method. Therefore null check like this:

```
if (myArray[position] == null) {
    ....

}
```

Comment: Derp, you're totally right. I was putting strings in my array cells and was just on a ".equals" kick. Works fine now! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

don't do .equals(null) but == null:

```
if( the_array[i] == null ) {
  //...
}
```

Think about build a table by a bidimensional array. Example:

```
TheClass my_array[][] = new TheClass[10][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
if (cell[i] == null){


}
```

since you are testing for reference equality. And in the case where cell[i] is actually null,  null doesnt have an equals method.

Answer (score 0):

Mixed up for loops and `null` construct

```
for(Integer ints : intNum) {
    if(intNum != null) {
      //valid
    }
}
```

Comment: small correction: it's (int != null) there's an = too many there. Prly a typo. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm more curious as to why your making 5 arrays? Have you heard of multidimensional arrays? Maybe that's what you really need in this case.

an array like this fx:
    int[][] arrayName = new int[3][3];

Would represent an array of 3 rows and 3 columns in each.

Maybe you alrdy knew that, but it just seems weird to me to make five different arrays if you just want a table-like structure.

Comment: It's going to be part of a table representation of a recursive parse tree. I could do a multi-dimensional array, but rather than maintain another integer through recursion, I'll just access the array name for that column.